# WTforms form not submitting but outputs no validation errors

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to get file uploads with `flask-uploads` working and running in to some snags. I'll show you my `flask` view function, the html and hopefully someone can point out what I'm missing.

Basically what happens is that I submit the form and it fails the `if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():` check in the view function. It jumps down to display the template. wtforms isn't kicking me any errors on the form so I'm wondering why its failing that if statement.

What am I over looking?

Setting up flask-uploads:

```
# Flask-Uploads
photos = UploadSet('photos',  IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, (photos))
```

View:

```
def backend_uploadphoto():
    from Application import photos
    from Application.forms.backend import AddPhotoForm

    clients = Client.query.all()
    events = Event.query.order_by('date').all()

    form = AddPhotoForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=True)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        from uuid import uuid4

        uuid = uuid4()
        filename = '{0}.jpg'.format(uuid)

        photo = Photo(uid=uuid, client=request.form['client'], event=request.form['event'])

        photofile = photos.save(request.files.get('photo'), photo.filename)

        return redirect(url_for('backend'))

    return render_template('backend/addphoto.html', form=form, clients=clients, events=events)
```

Form:

```
class AddPhotoForm(Form):
    photo = FileField('Photo')
    client = IntegerField('Client:')
    event = IntegerField('Event:')
```

HTML:

```
<form action="{{url_for('backend_uploadphoto')}}" method="post">
        <p>
            {{form.client.label}}
            <select name="client">
                {% for client in clients %}
                <option value="{{client.id}}">{{client.fullname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {{form.client.errors}}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{form.event.label}}
            <select name="event">
                {% for event in events %}
                <option value="{{event.id}}">{{event.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {{form.event.errors}}
        </p>

        <p><label for="photo">Photo:</label>{{form.photo}} <input type="submit" value="Upload"> {{form.photo.errors}}</p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Well if you using Flask, I would say - try Flask-WTF.

Comment: @IgnasButėnas Been getting a similar error all week, but it's definitely not CSRF related, unfortunately = (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `csrf_enabled=True` but your form doesn't have any CSRF protection since you aren't inheriting from `SecureForm`. If you want to enable CSRF, read the [documentation](http://packages.python.org/WTForms/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.csrf) and update your form definition.

If this was unintended, you can remove `csrf_enabled=True` and your logic will work as expected.

To enable CSRF protection, there are a few steps:

1. Inherit from `SecureForm`
2. Create the `generate_csrf_token` and `validate_csrf_token` methods in your form. These methods will generate a unique key and raise errors when it doesn't validate.
3. Add `{{ form.csrf_token }}` to your template.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: hey i know this is too late but is there any way that flask-wtf throw an error when there is an validation error not to the fields but to the flask debugger or the command line?